# Want to hide the cmd prompt screen

Tags: c#, .net, command, cmd

I have developed a utility which will get time of all servers in the list.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p;
string server_name = "";
string[] output;
p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StandardOutput.ReadLine().ToString()
```

While executing this code. *Cmd* prompt screens are coming. I want to hide it from the user. What can I do for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can tell the process to use no window or to minimize it:

```
// don't execute on shell
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

// don't show window
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
```

with `UseShellExecute = false` you may redirect the output:

```
// redirect standard output as well as errors
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

When you do this, you should use asynchronous reading of the output buffers to avoid a deadlock due to overfilled buffers:

```
StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder errorString = new StringBuilder();

p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    outputString.AppendLine("Info " + e.Data);
                }
            };

p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    errorString.AppendLine("EEEE " + e.Data);
                }
            };
```

Comment: UseShellExecute = false will also allow you to redirect STDOUT and STDERR into streams that can be useful.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan I left it out because the OP already did it.

Comment: yes you are right, my bad. Although, personally I feel RedirectStandardError is more important.

Answer (score 5):

Try with [`ProcessWindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx) enumeration like this;

```
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

> The hidden window style. A window can be either visible or hidden. The
>   system displays a hidden window by not drawing it. If a window is
>   hidden, it is effectively disabled. A hidden window can process
>   messages from the system or from other windows, but it cannot process
>   input from the user or display output. Frequently, an application may
>   keep a new window hidden while it customizes the window's appearance,
>   and then make the window style Normal. To use
>   **ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden**, the **ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute**
>   property must be **false**.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this both

```
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

or check this also

**To run the child process without any window,**

use the CreateNoWindow property and set UseShellExecute.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arg); 
info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process processChild = Process.Start(info);
```

I suggest you to go throught this post of MSDN : [**How to start a console app in a new window, the parent's window, or no window**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/createnowindow.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add a System Reference.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Then use this code to run your command in a hiden CMD Window.

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "Enter your command here";
cmd.Start();
```